# show() and hide() not working but toggle working... If condition wrong?

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code where `show()` and `hide()` are not working:

```js
var action = 0;
var toggle = 0;

$(function() {
  $('.button-work1').on('click', function() {
    if ($toggle == 0) {
      $action = 1;
      $toggle = 1;
      $('.showData').show();
    } else {
      $('.showData').hide();
      $toggle = 0
    }
  });
});
```

When I use `toggle()` and remove the if condition it worke fine. However, I don't want to use `toggle()` as I need to do few more things based on `$toggle` value.

Comment: Don't forget, when using `.toggle` you can use `var isVisible = $( "#myDiv" ).is( ":visible" );var isHidden = $( "#myDiv" ).is( ":hidden" );` to check the state of the visibility (as opposed to using variables) { Taken from: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $ in front of your variable names, this is Javascript not PHP :)

```js
    var action=0;
    var toggle=1;

$(function() {
    $('.button-work1').on('click', function() {
        if(toggle == 0){
        action = 1;
        toggle=1;
        $('.showData').show();}
        else{
        $('.showData').hide();
        toggle=0
        }            
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showData">Test element</div>

<input type="button" value="click me" class="button-work1">
```